# Innodb: Operating System Error number 5 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve the data from MySQL ibd file but facing following error.

`140601 17:00:45 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140601 17:00:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140601 17:00:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140601 17:00:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140601 17:00:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140601 17:00:45 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140601 17:00:45 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140601 17:00:45 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140601 17:00:45  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Error: tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 136 2748317696.
InnoDB: Was only able to read -1.
140601 17:00:45  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 5 means 'Input/output error'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File operation call: 'read'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.`

Please help me out from this issue.

Thanks

Comment: To get a better answer, try posting the code that causes the issue.

Comment: Off-topic and belongs on [dba.se]

Answer (score 1):

Given the log indication of starting recovery, then getting a failed read, this sounds consistent with a hard drive failure. You can see the same output with that as the diagnosis at http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-70181.html and https://serverfault.com/questions/315664/mysql-wont-start, with the first answer in that second link showing a way to recover.